# JavaScript client cant read cookie with XSRF token set by Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, cookies, spring-boot

I am developing some public API. I would like to introduce XSRF security to my project. API is hosted under `services.mydomain.com`. I have also client hostend under user.mydomain.com. The problem is that my JS client can't read cookie set up by server. I am trying for example to execute `document.cookie` and it responds with empty string. What I am doing wrong?

Cookie have following attributes (on browser end):

[image]

This is how I am setting up cookie:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        }
```

Comment: If you are using a cookie for XSRF I think you should go back and read about the XSRF vulnerability again. The entire idea, is that *it should NOT be a cookie*, but part of the POST either as a parameter or a header.

Comment: Typically you would use send the XSRF as a header with spring

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek XSRF tokens are sent to client as cookies and the client sends the token back as a header. This is standard way to do it. This is how Spring does it, this is how Angular does it. The problem here is that the browser can't read the cookie so it cannot send the header.

Comment: Cookies can be configured as HttpOnly. This is should always be the case with session cookies, to prevent JavaScript from reading them. If you send the XSRF token as a cookie make sure it is not HttpOnly. When I have a single page application, the page is typically a thyme-leaf template, and I just assign the XSRF token to a javascript global variable, then I don't need any cookie.